# Object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I'm using a C# aspx web form with a WebMethod but I have a problem trying to call a class with public methods, I get this error message:

> an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property.

Here is an example of my code.

**DB_Class**

```
public int Cuenta(User us, int opcion)
{
    string sql = "";
    int res = 0;

    switch (opcion)
    {
        //Insert
        case 1:
            sql = "query...";
            break;
            //Update
        case 2:
            sql = "";
            break;
            //Delete
        case 3:
            sql = "";
            break;
    }
    //More code, using executenonquery etc. there is no problem with that.
    return res;
}
```

**ASPX, Webmethod code**

```
db_Class conn = new db_Class();

[WebMethod]
public static string RegistrarCuenta(int id, string usuario, string nombre, string apellido, string email, string password, string fechaNacimiento, int tipo, int op)
{
    string respuesta = "Ha Ocurrido Un error.";

    try
    {
        User us = new User(id, usuario, nombre, apellido, email, password, fechaNacimiento, tipo);
        //I get the error here.
        int resp = conn.Cuenta(us, op);

        if (resp > 0)
            respuesta = "Operacion Realizada Correctamente.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        respuesta = "Ha Ocurrido un error: " + ex.Message;
    }

    return respuesta;
}
```

I look here for solutions but I dont found anything like my problem (trying to call a method in another class). Also I tried to change my webmethod to public string intead of public static string but with this now I get this browser error: Unknown web method, I dont know if this problem is for a bad url reference in my ajax code, here is my **ajax** code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'registrar.aspx/RegistrarCuenta',
            data: '{' +
                '"id":' + id +
                ',"usuario":"' + user +
                '","nombre":"' + nombre +
                '","apellido":"' + apellido +
                '","email":"' + email +
                '","password":"' + password +
                '","fechaNacimiento":"' + date +
                '","tipo":' + 2 +
                ',"op":' + 1 + '}',
            dataType: "json",               // Tipo de datos que se envian
            contentType: "application/json",            // Tipo de datos qu se envian
            timeout: 60000,             // Tiempo de espera para que occura un error de timeout
            error: function (xhr) {     // Evento que se dispara al ocurrir un error en la peticion
                swal("Algo a salido mal...", "Error!", "error")
            },
            success: function (data) {   // Evento que se dispara cuando se realiza correctamente
                swal(data.d, "", "success");
            }
        });
```

PD. registrar.aspx is located on my root folder, no inside a subfolder, etc. in the root.

How can I solve my problem? Or what can I change to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`conn` is an instance member, it can't be accessed in a static context because there's no instance to use.

More to the point, using shared connection objects (*especially* in a static context) is generally a very bad idea.  Just create the connection object where/when you need it:

```
db_Class conn = new db_Class();
int resp = conn.Cuenta(us, op);
```

You can (and probably should) remove the class-level `conn` member and keep the scope of connections very small.  If it implements `IDisposable`, you should also take advantage of that:

```
int resp = 0;
using (db_Class conn = new db_Class())
{
    resp = conn.Cuenta(us, op);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In C# or Java,

You can not access non-static members ( variables or functions) in a static method. Either you declare them static or initialize local variable in your web method as @David is suggesting.

check this link also
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx